# make the text for all textbox blue

Tags: asp.net, css, vb.net

I currently have vb as below:

```
 Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Textbox1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue
End Sub
```

My multiline textbox is

```
  <asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="300px" Width="99.6%" ENABLED="false" ></asp:TextBox>
```

I have 100 textboxes. I wonder if there is a simple code that can make all of my textboxes blue?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best to use CSS for this:

```
input[type=text] { color: blue; }
```

It's good practice to have this style defined in a `css` file and reference it from your asp.net page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
```

Comment: use `textarea` instead of `input[type=text]`

Comment: yeah, i tried that too, doesn't work, i guess because i'm using asp.net?

Comment: `textarea` should work since that's what ASP.NET will generate

Comment: You could write `input[type=text], textarea { color: blue; }`

Comment: That would make all the textboxes blue. If you specifically want only multiline textboxes to be blue, then this is not the right approach. This would be a good fit only if you want all textboxes and all textarea's to be blue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use this for styling all input elements on a page which have  type as text:

```
input[type=text] {

}
```

So, if you want to have the background color as Blue, then you will have to use:

```
input[type=text] {
    background-color: Blue;
    }
```

Now, if you want the text instead of background color to be blue, then you will have to use:

```
input[type=text] {
    color: Blue;
    }
```

Please see this link here: http://jsfiddle.net/BPPQw/

Hope this helps!!!

**EDIT : Multiline textbox in ASP.NET**

You have to understand that multiline textboxes in ASP.NET are rendered as 'textarea' in html.
You can see by using 'Inspect element' in the browser (Chrome, Firefox etc).

Hence, you will have to style the textarea element.

So, to make the background color Blue for a multiline textbox, you will need to use:

```
textarea {
background-color: Blue;
}
```

Comment: thank you,  if it's multiline, do I write type=multiline-text?

Comment: No. You don't need to write multiline. All textboxes are rendered in HTML as <input type = "text">. So this will work with all textboxes whether multiline or not.

Comment: i'm using asp text box in visual studio, and the code only makes singline textbox blue, not multiline..

Comment: user `textarea {color:blue;}` for multiline textboxes

Answer (score 0):

The best way is using css

```
input[type=text] {
   color:blue;
}
```

For multiline textbox use this css:

```
textarea {
    color:blue;
}
```

But if you want to do that programmatically, you can iterate through Page.Controls collection and if the type of control is TextBox you can use a type cast and set the color to each one.